# Rewrite code with two loops and two output statements

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, output

I am working on completing the summer assignment for my AP Computer Science A class. The base code for the next portion is this:

```
public class Stars {

public static void main(String[] args) {


System.out.println("*");
System.out.println("**");
System.out.println("***");
System.out.println("****");
System.out.println("*****");
 }
}
```

*RESULT*:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I am supposed to rewrite the code to output the same result, using two loops as well as only two output statements that I will provide below:

```
System.out.print(“*”);
System.out.println();
```

I have found one alternative means to do so:

```
public class StarsLoop {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
  System.out.print("*\n**\n***\n****\n*****");
 }
}
```

Of course, though, this does not include two loops and the two given output statements as is required; however, I can't really seem to think of how I would do so. So, what is a possible way to do so?

Comment: Outer loop for the  number of lines to print.  Inner loop with the number of * to print.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of nested loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to print five lines in total, each line consists of the line number star characters. Loop from one to five (inclusive), and inside that loop - loop again, this time the outer number of times printing stars. After that, print a newline. Like,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Of course, you could eliminate a loop by accumulating stars in a `StringBuilder` - and outputing that on each iteration. Like,

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder("*");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line.append("*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will produce the desired result:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) // Loop over each asterisks row to be printed

    for(int j = 0;j < i; j++) { // Loop over the number of stars to print for the current line. It is based on the current row number

        System.out.print(“*”); // Add an asterisks to the current row
    }

    System.out.println(); // Move to the next line
 }
```